# tune.svm Error: is.atomic(x) is not TRUE

Tags: r, svm, libsvm

I am trying to use tune svm where I have:

```
KERNEL="polynomial"
DEGREE = 2
TunedModel <- tune.svm(trainSet,trainClasses,cost=1:10, type="C-classification", 
            kernel = KERNEL, degree = DEGREE, coef0=1, 
            cachesize = 10000, cross = 10)
```

and I get the error:

```
Error: is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
```

This works without tune using just svm from the package "e1071". Is there a step I must take before this?